# What does RowDefinition Height="10*" mean in a XAML Grid?

Tags: wpf, xaml, grid

I use Height="*" a bit to mean that the height of the last row should fill to the bottom of the grid.

But what does "10*" mean?

```
<Grid Name="mainGrid">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="100" />
        <RowDefinition Height="40" />
        <RowDefinition Height="10*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="200"  />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 118, accepted):

`"*"` is shorthand for `"1*"`. It's a ratio, so if you have two rows, one with `"*"` and one with `"10*"`, the former gets 1/11th of the available and the latter gets 10/11th of the space.

In your example above, `"10*"` is unnecessary - `"*"` would make more sense because there is only one row using ratio-based sizing, so any ratio will equate to 100% of the available space.

Comment: Very helpful answer. Official documentation's limited examples don't explicitly declare a '*' to indicate ratio based spacing.

Comment: @ford it does but you need to change the version to silverlight [link]http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.grid.rowdefinitions(v=vs.95).aspx

Answer (score 25):

I found the info below from Christian Mosers to be helpful since the Auto, and Fixed sizes on other cells rows or columns will influence the behavior of the * size.  See http://wpftutorial.net/GridLayout.html

---

**Fixed** 
Fixed size of logical units (1/96 inch)

**Auto** 
Takes as much space as needed by the contained control

**Star**(*)
Takes as much space as available (after filling all auto and fixed sized columns), proportionally divided over all star-sized columns. So 3*/5* means the same as 30*/50*. Remember that star-sizing does not work if the grid size is calculated based on its content.

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="28" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="200" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
</Grid>
```